# Distance between points maximally distributed on n-dimensional unit sphere?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

This problem arose in some of my own personal data science research and I am wondering if anyone has encountered this before.

Consider $k$ points that lie on an $n$-dimensional unit sphere such that all pairs of points are as far apart as possible. Is there a closed-form solution to finding this distance?

First I tried solving it in a simpler case of a 2-dimensional sphere, i.e a circle. In this case, the problem reduces to finding the length of one side of a regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle. Using some simple trigonometry we can derive a formula for the length of one side of this polygon:

$$d = 2 \sin \frac{\pi}{k}$$

where $d$ is the distance between any pair of points and $k$ is the number of points.

So in 2-dimensions, this is the furthest distance between any two points on a unit circle such that all pairs of points are the same distance apart. It seems that one could similarly solve this in 3-dimensions by inscribing solids inside the sphere and finding their side lengths, though I am unsure of how to approach this, let alone $n$-dimensions.

Is it possible to find a general solution to this problem when we have $k$ points lying on an $n$-dimensional unit sphere?

Thank you to anyone who can offer insights or help! Please let me know if anything needs further clarification.

Comment: You can find an absolute upper limit by dividing the surface area of the $n$-dimensional sphere by $k$, and then finding the radius of an $n$-dimensional circle ($n-1$-dimensional sphere) with that area.  The absolute upper limit is then twice that radius.  Typically, the actual minimum distance for a given $n$ and $k$ is slightly smaller, as circles do not tile a surface.

Comment: Because the n-sphere is compact, you're likely to bump into correct solutions by just selecting k points on the sphere at random, and then applying gradient descent and annealing to maximize the minimum distance between them. How the resulting points  are distributed might give some insight into the problem.  I'm sure 4 points on the sphere go for a regular tetrahedron, 8 will settle into a regular octahedron, and 12 into an icosahedron.  But I wonder how 5 would do for example, and what shape would that give us.